# parse a log file for errors on a specific date

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Thank you for any help in advance! :)

I am a beginner to `Powershell`. I have the `powershell` app, not `powershell ISE`. I need to parse through a log file GENERATED BY MY BACKUPSOLUTION APP INTO A RTF DOCUMENT and look for the word `"Errors: "` in the last 24-72 hours. I basically have to see when my backup solution for my laptop is failing me.

I have the following so far:

```
     $daysBack = 3
$refDate  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysBack).Date  # set this to midnight
$log      = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\<User>\Documents\TheLog.log'

# find lines that start with what looks like a date and contains 'Errors:'
# capture the date part in backreference $matches[1] to parse into a real datetime object for comparison with $refDate
$errors = @($log | Where-Object { $_ -match '(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*Errors:' } |   
                   Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null) -ge $refDate }).Count

# if $errors not 0
if ($errors) {
    $count = if ($errors -eq 1) { "was an error" } else { "were $errors errors" }
    "There {0} in your back up solution in the last $daysBack days. Please check your log file." -f $count
}
else {
    "There were no errors in backing up your files in the last $daysBack days."
}
```

The above code does not find the following error:

```
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - can not access C:\users\<username>\documents\ The network path was not found.
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - End: Desktop... Copied: 0, Errors: 1
```

***Sample lines from my logfile that show a successful copy:**

```
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - Begin: Documents=======================================
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - copied Notes.docx from C:\users\<username>\documents\ to D:\users\<username>\documents\
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - End: Documents...Copied 1
```

***Sample lines that show an unsuccessful copy from a few days back in the log file:**

```
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - can not access C:\users\<username>\documents\ The network path was not found.

18/02/2021 08:57:37 - End: Documents... copied: 0, Errors: 1
```

I should also mention there are sometimes when I delete a file from my documents and rather than back it up it deletes from the back up as well. As far as I understand my backup solution is an exact mirror of whatever is in my documents. I think I would like to maybe include something about these deletes in my code too.

MY LOG FILE IS A RTF FORMAT
***Sample section of log file that deletes:**

```
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - End: Documents...Copied 1, Deleted: 1
```

*EDITTTTTTTTT* I have several errors in this document.

This was my prior code:

My code was very simple:

```
Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\<User>\Documents\TheLog.log' -select string "Errors: "
```

But I wanted something that could filter the errors based on critical errors but have no idea how
When I run the above code I get this output:

```
\par 18/02/2021 08:57:37 - \plain\f0\fs16\cf1 End: Documents... copied: 0, Errors: 1 \plain\f0\fs16\cf1
```

I want to somehow extract that date from that generated string and compare it to today's date.

Comment: Please edit your post to add a few sample lines from the logfile that show how timestamps are formatted.

Comment: Could you please share some (sanitized) sample content of your log file? Format it as code please.

Comment: It *really* depends on how the dates are formatted and where they are in each line. We'll need an example line

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful hints, apologies I am a complete newbie. But I shall try to write out the code I have:

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow @Yaz. You should always provide as much info as possible when writing a question, specially info that is important to answer. In this case you want us to process a file, so we need some example of that file :)  - I see you already try to write some code solve it yourself, that is very good indicator!! Happy learning!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you show the log file looks like, you can do below to test if there were errors reported in the last three days:

```
$daysBack = 3
$refDate  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysBack).Date  # set this to midnight
$log      = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\<User>\Documents\TheLog.log'

# find lines that start with what looks like a date and contains 'Errors:'
# capture the date part in backreference $matches[1] to parse into a real datetime object for comparison with $refDate
$errors = @($log | Where-Object { $_ -match '(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*Errors:' } |   
                   Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null) -ge $refDate }).Count

# if $errors not 0
if ($errors) {
    $count = if ($errors -eq 1) { "was an error" } else { "were $errors errors" }
    "There {0} in your back up solution in the last $daysBack days. Please check your log file." -f $count
}
else {
    "There were no errors in backing up your files in the last $daysBack days."
}
```

---

I have tested with a file:

```
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - can not access C:\users\<username>\documents\ The network path was not found.
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - End: Documents... copied: 0, Errors: 1
21/02/2021 08:57:37 - can not access C:\users\<username>\documents\ The network path was not found.
21/02/2021 08:57:37 - End: Documents... copied: 0, Errors: 1
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - Begin: Documents=======================================
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - copied Notes.docx from C:\users\<username>\documents\ to D:\users\<username>\documents\
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - End: Documents...Copied 1
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - End: Documents...Copied 1, Deleted: 1
```

and today is **23/02/2021**

When setting

```
$daysBack = 3
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-3).Date  # set this to midnight
```

The output is

```
There was an error in your back up solution in the last 3 days. Please check your log file.
```

When setting to 6 days back:

```
$daysBack = 6
$refDate  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysBack).Date  # set this to midnight
```

The output is as expected:

```
There were 2 errors in your back up solution in the last 6 days. Please check your log file.
```

---

Regex details:

```
(                Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d            Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}        Exactly 2 times
   /             Match the character “/” literally
   \d            Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}        Exactly 2 times
   /             Match the character “/” literally
   \d            Match a single digit 0..9
      {4}        Exactly 4 times
   \             Match the character “ ” literally
   \d            Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}        Exactly 2 times
   :             Match the character “:” literally
   \d            Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}        Exactly 2 times
   :             Match the character “:” literally
   \d            Match a single digit 0..9
      {2}        Exactly 2 times
)               
.                Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *             Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
Errors:          Match the characters “Errors:” literally
```

Comment: I have just tried this and it worked I have been on this for 6 days!  THANK YOU SO MUCH! May I ask what you recommend for a total beginner like me to learn powershell? are there any specific courses?

Comment: @Yaz Thanks for the nice feedback. About learning PowerShell, there is lots to be found on the internet. [Here](https://adamtheautomator.com/search/powershell) might be a good start

Comment: my apologies to bother you! I checked again the code above actually ends up always giving me the "There were no errors..." message. Also with the $refdate variable I need to set that date to "dd/MM/yyyy" format. with the $errors variable if I change the date from 3 days to the last 6 days when there was definitely an error - it tells me there were no errors so the script cannot find the errors for some reason. Any advice?

Comment: @Yaz No, you need both dates as **Datetime** objects to compare correctly.

Comment: ah ok, any idea why if I change the AddDays(-3) bit to AddDays(-6) why it can't find my errors? I don't think it is parsing at all for some reasons

Comment: @Yaz Are you sure your examples are correct and each line starts with the date in dd/MM/yyyy format? I have added the data I used for testing and the test results. Seems correct to me.. I also added the details for the regex

Comment: @Yaz I have extended the regex to now include the Time part (although not really needed) and also by looking at the duplicate question you've posted, I added `\s*` in there too because lines may have leading spaces ?? About _ filter the nonsense errors from the useful errors_ .. You'll have to define what is nonsense and what not then. This will make the regex really complicated.

Comment: Hi Theo, I am so frustrated as I am sure I am doing something wrong but when I set it to 9 days back it does not find my error. I have checked my file path, that's great it finds the file and extracts the content. I have checked my log file I don't see any difference between mine and the section I posted above. So I am just lost

Comment: Theo just to clarify I am sure you are right and I will mark your answer up but I cannot see where I am going wrong

Comment: @Yaz Can you show me the line(s) exactly as they are that it didn't pick up? Sometimes, two see more than one.

Comment: Sure thing the $errors variable above does not return any errors even if set the date back by 9 days one sec I will show you.

Comment: 18/02/2021 08:57:37 - can not access C:\users\<username>\documents\ The network path was not found.
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - End: Desktop... Copied: 0, Errors: 1                                                              This does not get found by the errors variable above

Comment: @Yaz That doesn't seem 'normal' text, more like [LaTex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82664/when-to-use-par-and-when-newline-or-blank-lines) or RTF.. I have removed the `^\s*` from the regex and if I test with that new example it works on that line too. Did something or someone open the log file and saved it again using a word-processing app?

Comment: OH MY GOODNESS! I did not know that affects the code please see my updated question above. my log file is a  RTF document. I am so sorry I had no idea that changes things.

Comment: @Yaz If I had known this is in RTF format I wouldn't have answered. Why is the log in that almost impossible to parse format anyway? Normally a backup application or Robocopy writes plain text. If you have no choice but to scan trhough RTF, you will need a Word.Application solution which complicates thing **enormously** unless you first convert it back to plain text, then my answer would work.

Comment: I will be honest with you I have no choice but to parse through this RTF document as it the backup solution belongs to my company and I have to find a solution for them. The application they use logs everything in this RTF file, I have no control over this.

Comment: @Yaz I think that is beyond the scope of **this** question.. You should post a new question on how to convert an RTF file into a plain text file. Once you have code for that, simply add my solution below that and all will be fine. I think I can answer that but I have to think 'Word'. Possibly someone else is much more into that.

Comment: I was also asked to use powershell to parse it.

Comment: ahh ok I shall post that question thank you Theo!