# How to convert a log file that is an RTF format to plain text

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

I need to convert my log file that is generated from by backup solution app from RTF format to plain text continuously (as in make a whole new log that is an exact copy of that one that will always be an updated copy) in order to parse the log file for errors using a code I kindly got from another user (please find it below). Any Idea how to do this with code using powershell?

The code I have that can search a text file:

```
$daysBack = 3
$refDate  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysBack).Date  # set this to midnight
$log      = Get-Content -Path 'C:\Users\<User>\Documents\TheLog.log'

# find lines that start with what looks like a date and contains 'Errors:'
# capture the date part in backreference $matches[1] to parse into a real datetime object for comparison with $refDate
$errors = @($log | Where-Object { $_ -match '(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*Errors:' } |   
                   Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null) -ge $refDate }).Count

# if $errors not 0
if ($errors) {
    $count = if ($errors -eq 1) { "was an error" } else { "were $errors errors" }
    "There {0} in your back up solution in the last $daysBack days. Please check your log file." -f $count
}
else {
    "There were no errors in backing up your files in the last $daysBack days."
}
```

I have tested with a plain text file version of my log file below:

```
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - can not access C:\users\<username>\documents\ The network path was not found.
18/02/2021 08:57:37 - End: Documents... copied: 0, Errors: 1
21/02/2021 08:57:37 - can not access C:\users\<username>\documents\ The network path was not found.
21/02/2021 08:57:37 - End: Documents... copied: 0, Errors: 1
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - Begin: Documents=======================================
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - copied Notes.docx from C:\users\<username>\documents\ to D:\users\<username>\documents\
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - End: Documents...Copied 1
22/02/2021 17:27:33 - End: Documents...Copied 1, Deleted: 1
```

The above code does not work for RTF. Any help or any idea how to change the above code to fit my log file in RTF format?

USING THE BELOW CODE BY @THEO :)

```
Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.

At line:41 char:13

+             $word.Quit()

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage

 

Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.

At line:42 char:13

+             $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Release ...

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage

 

Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.

At line:43 char:13

+             $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::Release ...

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage

 

Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.

At line:44 char:13

+             [System.GC]::Collect()

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage

 

Cannot invoke method. Method invocation is supported only on core types in this language mode.

At line:45 char:13

+             [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()

+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodInvocationNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage

 

Cannot set property. Property setting is supported only on core types in this language mode.

At line:17 char:9

+         $word.Visible = $false

+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertySetterNotSupportedInConstrainedLanguage

 

Get-Content : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.

At line:55 char:31

+ $log      = Get-Content -Path $plainTextLog

+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-Content], ParameterBindingValidationException

    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentC

   ommand
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert from RTF to plain-text file, you can use the following helper function:

```
function ConvertFrom-RTF {
  [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('FullName')]
        [string]$Path
    )

    # this is the output format
    # see:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat?view=word-pia
    $WdSaveFormat = 3   # wdFormatTextLineBreaks

    try {
        $word = New-Object -ComObject Word.Application
        $word.Visible = $false
        $doc = $word.Documents.Open($Path)
        # Replace the source file extenson with the appropriate target file extension 
        $fileOut = [System.IO.Path]::ChangeExtension($Path, '.txt')

        if (Test-Path -Path $fileOut -PathType Leaf) {
            # Delete existing file
            Remove-Item -Path $fileOut -Force -Confirm:$false
        }
        # Check Version of Office Installed. Pre 2010 versions need [ref] on the parameters
        if ($word.Version -gt '14.0') {
            $doc.SaveAs($fileOut, $WdSaveFormat)
        }
        else {
            $doc.SaveAs([ref]$fileOut,[ref]$WdSaveFormat)
        }
        $doc.Close($false)

        # return the filename of the converted file
        return $fileOut
    }
    finally {
        # cleanup code
        if ($word) {
            $word.Quit()
            $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($doc)
            $null = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($word)
            [System.GC]::Collect()
            [System.GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
        }
    }
}

# the returned value is the full path and filename of the converted text file
$plainTextLog = ConvertFrom-RTF -Path 'C:\Users\<User>\Documents\TheLog.rtf'
```

Below that, add the code you already have from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66331834/9898643) to parse the log:

```
$daysBack = 3
$refDate  = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$daysBack).Date  # set this to midnight
$log      = Get-Content -Path $plainTextLog

# find lines that start with what looks like a date and contains 'Errors:'
# capture the date part in backreference $matches[1] to parse into a real datetime object for comparison with $refDate
$errors = @($log | Where-Object { $_ -match '(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}).*Errors:' } |   
                   Where-Object { [datetime]::ParseExact($matches[1], 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', $null) -ge $refDate }).Count

# if $errors not 0
if ($errors) {
    $count = if ($errors -eq 1) { "was an error" } else { "were $errors errors" }
    "There {0} in your back up solution in the last $daysBack days. Please check your log file." -f $count
}
else {
    "There were no errors in backing up your files in the last $daysBack days."
}
```

Comment: apologies Theo I did not realise, you had to do that! I have tried the code it indeed gives me the correct error messages! Despite it giving me a lot of red error messages? I am going to put them in here, not sure if it has anything to do with my version of word, which is Microsoft office Home and Business 2019??

Comment: @Yaz I can only test with my version of MS Word, which is version 2016 Pro and with that, there are no error messages.. Please show them

Comment: This is so frustrating, it has stopped working all together now

Comment: @Yaz Go into TaskManager and killl all Word instances. It'll run after that, but the main thing is to see what error messages you get with that version of Word

Comment: I have posted the error message in my original post above

Comment: I closed all word documents and sadly the code stopped recognising errors, sorry for this bother Theo

Comment: @Yaz Looks like you need to set `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'FullLanguage'` first. (probably do this when running as Administrator. (see [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-constrained-language-mode/))

Comment: ahh I should have mentioned I am not an adminstrator for this laptop and I am not allowed to be, so have to work within the rights I have sadly :(

Comment: Do I simply add this to the top of your code?  $ExecutionContext.SessionState.LanguageMode = 'FullLanguage'

Comment: @Yaz yes, you start with that to hopefully allow the code to use a Word.Application COM object. Perhaps you need to talk to your system administrator.. If your task is to be able to parse these rtf files, you should be allowed to do so. Another app that can open rtf files is WordPad, but unfortunately that has no programmable interface like Word has.

Comment: @Yaz If it is because of a group-policy setting, show your system administrator [this](https://4sysops.com/archives/mitigating-powershell-risks-with-constrained-language-mode/#switching-to-constrained-mode-with-an-environment-variable) and ask to please set the value to `8` (--> FullLanguage)